# Subscript out of bounds error while mosaicking TIFFs together

Tags: raster, r, google-earth-engine, mosaic, rgdal

I have just downloaded NDVI imagery from Google Earth Engine. The image was too big so it was divided into about 35 .tif files. Each tile has approximately 950 bands of NDVI values.

I am now trying to stitch the images back together in R. I have tried two different methods:

The first method which uses the *raster* package is really slow:

```
library(raster)

f <- list.files(path = "/scratch/MODIS_NDVI_TIFS", pattern = ".tif$", full.names = TRUE)

rl <- lapply(f, raster::brick)

m <- do.call(raster::mosaic, rl)

writeRaster(m,"APL_NDVI_Combined.tif")
```

The second method I found discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876591/merging-multiple-rasters-in-r) which I modified for my use as such:

```
library(gdalUtils)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)


f <- list.files(path = "/scratch/MODIS_NDVI_TIFS", pattern = ".tif$", full.names = TRUE)


e <- extent(113.338953078, 153.569469029,-43.6345972634, -10.6681857235)

template <- raster(e)
proj4string(template) <- '+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs '

writeRaster(template, file="Combine_NDVI.tif", format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)

mosaic_rasters(gdalfile=f,dst_dataset="Combine_NDVI.tif",of="GTiff")
```

However, I get an error in during the *moasic_rasters* call which states:

```
Error in strsplit(gsub(grep(cmd_output, pattern = "Size is ", value = TRUE),  : 
subscript out of bounds
Calls: mosaic_rasters -> gdalinfo
Execution halted
```

Any idea what is going on here? Are there better suggestions for combining these rasters together?

Comment: The appropriate `raster` method would be `raster::merge(, overlap=FALSE)`. That should be faster than `mosaic`. Or try `terra::merge`

Answer (score 2):

This Q & A should work, although you may run into memory issues depending on RAM etc

[Error while combining multiple partially overlapping rasters into a single raster in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261308/error-while-combining-multiple-partially-overlapping-rasters-into-a-single-raste/262962#262962)

Comment: What package does ```mosaicList``` come from?

Comment: mosaicList is a custom function, detailed earlier in the thread- mainly built on raster